# I got stuck in SQL select that has exactly multiple values

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-division

```
Table name: test
id - student - class
1 - Jane - A
2 - David - B
3 - Jane - C
4 - Nick - A
5 - Nick - B
6 - Smith - C
----------------
```

Now I want to find out Student name that enrolled both A and C class (must be A and C)
the result will show Jane because she enrolled in both A and C

p/s: Im using MS - ACCESS 2007

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please provide your DBMS. Or the question will likely be deleted as unclear.

Comment: sorry abt lack of information. Im using MS ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the students and select only classes `A`and `C`. then take only those students having both entries

```
select student
from test
group by student
having sum(iif(class = 'A',1,0)) > 0
and sum(iif(class = 'B',1,0)) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks but it show Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'count (distinct class) = 2'

Comment: Hmmm. What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Im using MS ACCESS 2007

Comment: Oh. Access does nort support `distinct` AFAIK.

Comment: Perfect dude... it worked...
Can u explain me details abt these one. I really at basic SQL only. appriciated that !

Comment: You group by the students. Then you can use the `having` clause to look at all records for each student. The students you want to select need to have classes A and B. Since you look at multiple records of a student in a group you need to use aggregate functions like ´sum()`. In that sum is a case that sums up the number of correct classes. Do it doe A and B

Comment: `if(class='A') then 1 else 0` That condition return 1 for true and 0 for false. The `sum()` sums up those true condtions. At least once (`sum>0`) this must be true for a student for each class

Comment: appriciated dude ! Thanks a lots :D

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of [**relational division**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/relational-division/info). We have assembled an arsenal of techniques here:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879)

Should be among the fastest solutions:

```
SELECT student
FROM   test t1
JOIN   test t2 USING (student)
WHERE  t1.class = 'A'
AND    t2.class = 'C';
```

**MS Access** has a rather basic implementation of SQL. And it uses double quotes for strings (which contradicts the standard):

```
SELECT test.student
FROM   test
INNER  JOIN test AS t2 ON test.student = t2.student
WHERE  test.class = "A"
AND    t2.class = "C";
```

`DISTINCT` (or grouping of the result) is only needed if the combination `(student, class)` is not unique - which it should be in most use cases.

Comment: There's no t1.student available in the select-list here, thanks to USING(student). The columns available are t1.id, t1.class, t2.id, t2.class, and student.

Comment: It won't work. you even not mention about the 'class'

Comment: @MinhTrương: Sorry, typo, fixed.

Comment: @jarlh: `t1.student` would still be available and correct (at least in Postgres), even though the table qualification is not *necessary* after joining with `USING (student)`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, according to ANSI SQL it's not. Since no dbms specified here it's better to give a dbms independent answer.

Comment: Great, personally I don't really like JOIN USING just because of this somewhat odd behavior. (But still it's better than NATURAL JOIN...)

Comment: TRIED, but syntax Error at From <<<
Im using MS - ACCESS

Comment: @jarlh: In a self-join `USING` is reasonably safe.

Comment: @MinhTrương: Provided a simple form that should work in Access.

Comment: I tried as your MS Access syntax but still Syntact Error. Could u try it by your access ?

Comment: in Access, I just create a table name 'test'
and 3 column 'id', 'student', 'class'
then I filled records by hand one by one as above...
This just for test. Because my real Database is bigger than this. I just take one simple to test it

Comment: @MinhTrương: Must have been the quotes. Access uses double quotes for strings. Should work now.

Comment: yes, the final one can work. it still worked with single quote. And it should have distinct after select to get one Name. Anyway thanks a lots. It easy to understand. Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

Take name's of `A` Class students & `C` Class Students & do `Intersection` on these result set's

```
select distinct
 a.student
from
 test a
 inner join test b on a.id = b.id
 where a.class = 'A' and b.class= 'C'
```

Comment: could u replace a, b by student, class... im confusing sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUDENT 
FROM TEST T 
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM TEST T1 WHERE T.STUDENT = T1.STUDENT AND T1.CLASS='A') AND
EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM TEST T2 WHERE T.STUDENT = T2.STUDENT AND T2.CLASS='C');
```